# What is difference between a class variable and class instance?

Tags: java, oop, object, reference, swap

For Example, I have a class Car and I am having two objects BMW and Benz of Class Car.So for instantiating we have to declare a new variable something like;

`Car BMW = new Car();`

Now what if the object is declared as

`Car Benz;`

If the first one passes by reference and the second one passes by value, Can anyone help me in doing the swapping by instantiating the object with an example?

Comment: Pass by value and pass by reference refers to passing parameters to a function/method - which you don't mention anything about - please clarify your question. We might guess that you want to make a method to swap two variables, but it's better that you tell us what you want to accomplish.  Also - Java only supports pass-by value.

Comment: You have to understand the difference between **variables** and **objects** - you are writing as if these are the same thing. A variable *refers to* an object, it is not the object by itself. `Car Benz;` is just declaring a variable without initializing it, there is no object involved.

Comment: @nos That's great, but see i've done an experiment. In the mentioned code referred , please add this, `System.out.println(aDog);` which actually gives an Hexadecimal digit referring to address in register. Which means aDog is actually referring to a memory location. I am a beginner in java and actually I went through programming in java written by o'reilly which says that by default jave handles the parameters as pass by reference.

Comment: And my intention is to know the difference between the above two declarations. And of course I never noticed this swapping in java since I am in a belief that everything in java is pass by reference. So I also asked for the program to save the space and time. And it truly doesn't have any connection related to the actual question. i just want to know the difference between the mentioned declarations.

Comment: The difference between the two declarations is that the second one doesn't initialise `Benz`. If you tried to test that you either run into a compile-time error or `Benz` would be `null` (depending on how you do it). Neither is **pass**-by-anything, because you're not **pass**ing anything to a method, and Java doesn't have both pass-by-reference and pass-by-value.

Comment: @Dukeling thank you, now in the second declaration what is the value of BMW after initialization. Isn't it null. And there'd be no compile time error and the above declared one is a static variable. It shows no error until unless you are appending some properties to it since it is null. Please try on your own and let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: @shiva Yes, it's null, because you haven't done anything with the reference. I don't know what you mean by a "static variable" here since there's no `static` keyword. It's not an error because there's nothing wrong with declaring an uninitialized reference; it happens all the time.

Comment: @shiva Java is pass by value, regardless of what your oreilly book said. You can ofcourse pass a reference to a method, the reference gets passed by value (copied) to that method. However, it is still very unclear what your actual question is.. I also cannot add the `System.out.println(aDog);` line anywhere, you have not shown any code that defines what `aDog` is. Remember - we cannot see your screen or know what you have tried/not tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A{
    int count = 1;
}

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    A a = new A();
    A b = new A();
    b.count = 2;

    System.out.println("Before swap");

    System.out.println("A count : "+a.count);
    System.out.println("B count : "+b.count);

    A c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;

    System.out.println("Before swap");

    System.out.println("A count : "+a.count);
    System.out.println("B count : "+b.count);


}
```

}

Comment: you did not understand what I mean.  You can swap anything like this in main function. But I want you to swap by calling a function, something like a function `swap(a,b);` should actually make a as b and b as a. If you check pointers in C and C++ you would get more clarity.

Comment: @shiva Why? In any case, if you modify a function's parameters, the calling function won't see that change; parameter values are local to that function. If those parameters are references, and you change something *within* the referenced object, that change will be reflected in the calling function.

Comment: @Dave thank you for giving the geeks for geeks code. Actually I meant that program itself. Suppose in the code given above you did enter it as 'Car c1 = null; Car c2 = null;' and append the properties will the same work. If it works it means that java by default passes by reference to the functional parameters. One difference I observed in initializing the both ways is that the constructor doesn't work with the latter initialization.